# Adding Gif as watermark on video using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android

I am trying to place gif on video and play the gif continuously until the video ends.I have achieved it by using FFmpeg in android.Below is the code:

```
String[] command_try=new String[13];
    command_try[0]="-i";
    command_try[1]=video_path;
    command_try[2]="-i";
    command_try[3]=gifthumbnail;
    command_try[4]="-filter_complex";
    command_try[5]="overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:y=(main_h-overlay_h)/2";
    command_try[6]="-pix_fmt";
    command_try[7]="yuv420p";
    command_try[8]="-c:a";
    command_try[9]="copy";
    command_try[10]="-preset";
    command_try[11]="ultrafast";
    command_try[12]="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/video_24.mp4";
```

But it takes around 2-3 mins to save the video with gifs .Just let me how to reduce the processing time by adding or removing any code.

Comment: you are already using fastest attribute -preset ultrafast

Comment: @MilanTejani Thank you for replay.Yes I am using fastest attribute but it still takes around 3 or more minutes to save 10mb video.